# Should a PyGTK application's main class extend Gtk.Window or not?

Tags: python, class, object, window, pygtk

I am *very* new to Python programming and currently working on a small PyGTK application.

After searching and reading through various on-line tutorials I am a little confused about defining the main application's class. The two different methods I have seen are:

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.window.show()

    def main(self):
        gtk.main()

print __name__
if __name__ == "__main__":
    base = Base()
    base.main()
```

src: http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/ch-GettingStarted.html

...or...

```
import gtk

class PyApp(gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PyApp, self).__init__()

        self.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
        self.set_size_request(250, 150)
        self.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
        self.show()

PyApp()
gtk.main()
```

src: http://zetcode.com/gui/pygtk/firststeps/

I understand the principal of one class extending another / using it as a base object but I am unclear on the benefits of one method over the other here, can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pygtk you can inherit from any widgets but in this case second implementation have advantage over first. One important concept in OOP programming is encapsolate that refers to how to access to the class properties/attributes and methodes. on the both implementation of codes, window is public and programmer can direct access to the window. OOP programming comes for we interact with objects easy, on the first implementation if you want to get title of window instance you must type:

```
base.window.get_title()
```

but on the second you must type:

```
PyApp().get_title()
```

also you can append custom attributes, properties and methods to the second implementation that you need or override these things that inherited from parent, for example you can add main method to the PyApp similar below:

```
import gtk

class PyApp(gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PyApp, self).__init__()

        self.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
        self.set_size_request(250, 150)
        self.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
        self.show()

    def main(self):
        gtk.main()

app = PyApp()
app.main()
```

but if you want to share this class by others programmer without direct access to the window, first implementation is better of course plus tiny changes similar below code:

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.__window.show()

    def main(self):
        gtk.main()

print __name__
if __name__ == "__main__":
    base = Base()
    base.main()
```

double underline before any properties, attributes and methodes change scope of these to private.